# Error Exception EOLeSysError class not registered Class Not Found Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I can successfully import and install type library `*.OCX with Delphi 7`. (Project - import type library - add - ...)

But when I use that Component, it shows the following message:

```
Error EOLeSysError class not registered Class Not Registered.
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: You need to rephrase your explanation and question, it's very hard to follow you.Please keep in mind that many people here aren't native speakers and you need to communicate very clearly to enable them to understand and answer your question.

Comment: this should help http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa040803a.htm

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the .ocx is not registered with the systems COM registry. Normally you would run `regsvr32 SomeOCXFileName.ocx` to register the COM server, although different components sometimes have different ways of performing that registration.